# How to delete a user in Laravel (eloquent) without its relations?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have a laravel application and I want to delete the user record form users table but keep the data related to them like articles.

I have this function for article

```
public function userArticles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Application\Model\userArticles');
    }
```

I want to delete the user without deleting the articles from database, but when I do `$user->delete()` it deletes everything.

is there a way to keep the articles?

Comment: Did you define `onCascade` as delete for the tables?

Comment: another solution would be to reassign the articles to another "neutral" user before deleting which will prevent many regression from having an article without a user liked to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE YOUR MIGRATION **->onDelete('set null')**
It means when the user was deleted, the field will be null.

```
$table-> bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->index();
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('admins')->onDelete('set null');
```